# Initialise SQLite Database in Yesod Scaffolding Site

Tags: database, sqlite, haskell, yesod

I created a yesod project with `yesod init` dans chose SQLite database.

My question : How do we initialise the SQLite Database with initial entries in the `Yesod Scaffoled Site` at the launch? Where do we put our `insert` instructions in this Yesod Templace Site?

I'm talking about actually adding records to some existing tables.

The [Persistence chapter in the Yesod book](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent) explains how to insert a line in the database in the Handler of a ressource, but it doesn't explain how to add database entries at the start of the Yesod site (when the Yesod site is launched using `yesod devel` for example).

This is probably not an efficient way to proceed, so any suggestions on the completion of this task would be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you talking about setting up the tables? or are you asking about actually adding records to these tables? Why would you want to add records on every startup of the web app?

Comment: No, the tables are already set up in the `models` file. I'm talking about adding records to these tables.
I want to add records in the startup so that I can initialise the SQLite database (before every startup, I'll have to delete the .sqlite3 file). Is there a better way to do that other than adding records on every startup?

Answer (score 1):

I've never done this before since in my usual use case the DB is used for persistence across runs.

However I think the most appropriate place to do this would be in the `makeFoundation` function inside the `Application` module

Thats where your DB resources (connection pool etc...) are initialised.

Theres a line that looks something like this:

```
-- Perform database migration using our application's logging settings.
runLoggingT
    (Database.Persist.runPool dbconf (runMigration migrateAll) p)
    (messageLoggerSource foundation logger)
```

That sets up your tables, its probably just after this that you want to add your records.

I think the link in your question needs to be corrected, but the [Persistent chapter of the Yesod book](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent) that you referred to does have valid examples for inserting records in an `IO ()` action, so it should be able to get you the rest of the way.

Hope this helped